# What does "draft" refer to?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

Batman failed to recruit Aquaman:

> Batman: I found him. He said no.
>
> Alfred: So the **draft** stands at naught for two? Maybe a man who broods
> in a cave for a living isn't cut out to be a recruiter. Hmm?

What does "draft" refer to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [sports metaphor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft_(sports)).  Batman is trying to "recruit" heroes to his "team," and it's not going so well.  (He's zero for two attempts so far.)

> A draft is a process used in some countries (especially in North America) and sports to allocate certain players to teams. In a draft, teams take turns selecting from a pool of eligible players.
>
> <sub>source: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft_(sports))</sub>

Comment: Also draft  in USA is "[Compulsory recruitment for military service](https://www.lexico.com/definition/draft)".

Comment: @Oni If it were that kind of draft I don't think Batman would be having as much trouble. :)